# Binary Search Tree - Removing all ints greater than certain value

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I am trying to figure out how to remove all integers a such that `a > b` where a is any element within the binary search tree and `b` is the threshold number that all elements in the BST are compared to. Thus far I have:

```
public treeRemoveGreater(int x, BinaryNode node) {
       if (node.element > x) {
          //node.element accesses element of given node i.e. integer value
          remove(node.element);
       }
       else {
          //Traverse tree 
       }
```

My problem is figuring out how to traverse the tree accordingly. I know that there is an efficient manner about going about this because a full traversal of the tree is not needed necessarily, I am just unsure as how to proceed.

Comment: Think of it like this - you're removing an entire subtree.

Comment: When you get to a node, if it's greater than b - put its left subtree in its place and repeat. If it's less than b, continue down right subtree. If it's exactly b - prune right subtree and you're done (assuming multiple values of b go down the left subtree).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about BST's property. The parent node is equal or greater than child nodes to the left and equal or lesser than the nodes on right. So you need to find B and delete all the nodes to its right (Just make sure no node on right is equal to the B since yur condition is all a > b). Like Makoto said remove an entire subtree.

Answer (score 1):

```
                      |
                 +----8----+
                 |         |
            +----3----+    10------+
            |         |            |
            1     +---6---+    +---14  
                  |       |    |
                  4       7    13
```

Consider this BST, If u want to remove the elements which are greater than 6 then u have to remove

1. The right child/sub-tree of "6", So u can eliminate
2. But you have to traverse from the root. So check the root is greater than your 'a' (in this case 8>6) ,
3. Make the left sub-tree as the main tree(with root '3') and compare the root with your 'a', if it is still greater then repeat step 2 (or)
4. If the new root is smaller than 'a' then traverse toward it right child( here 3 !> 6, so from here on you are not going to touch the root)
5. Then check with the right node which is equal to 'a' in this case, so go to its right node to check whether you have duplicate elements which are equal to a( if exist then traverse to that node and set the right child of it to 'null'
6. In case while moving toward right u find a larger element than 6(in this case if u find 7 in the place of 6 and 6 in the place of 4), then u have to make the root of the sub tree with its left tree

   ```
        |                                 |
   +----7----+                            6
   |         |          ---->     
   6         7
   ```